# Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property territoryID found on com.common.model.EmployeeTerritory! - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing `Spring Boot MongoDB` example. In this example, I am trying to get TerritoryID by spring-data-mongo repository query and facing below error. Please guide

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property territoryID found on com.common.model.EmployeeTerritory!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:236) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:214) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:202) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:109) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:55) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.createQuery(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:75) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:86) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:415) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:506) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.findByTerritoryID(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.common.service.EmployeeTerritoryServiceImpl.findByTerritoryID(EmployeeTerritoryServiceImpl.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.common.main.MainController.run(MainController.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:672) [spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
16-03-22 22:33:38 [main] INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@576d5deb: startup date [Tue Mar 22 22:33:26 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
16-03-22 22:33:38 [main] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:675)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:690)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.common.main.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

The code I developed:
EmployeeTerritory.java

```
@Document(collection="employee-territories")
public class EmployeeTerritory {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @Field
    private String EmployeeID;
    @Field(value="TerritoryID")
    private Integer TerritoryID;
    // setters and getters
}
```

EmployeeTerritoryRepository.java

```
public interface EmployeeTerritoryRepository extends CrudRepository<EmployeeTerritory, String>{
    EmployeeTerritory findByTerritoryID(Integer territoryID);
}
```

EmployeeTerritoryService.java

```
public interface EmployeeTerritoryService {
    EmployeeTerritory findByTerritoryID(Integer territoryID);
}
```

EmployeeTerritoryServiceImpl.java

```
@Component
public class EmployeeTerritoryServiceImpl implements EmployeeTerritoryService{

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeTerritoryRepository employeeTerritoryRepository;


    @Override
    public EmployeeTerritory findByTerritoryID(Integer territoryID) {
        EmployeeTerritory et = employeeTerritoryRepository.findByTerritoryID(territoryID);
        return et;
    }
}
```

MainController.java

```
@Controller
public class MainController implements CommandLineRunner {
    private Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MainController.class);

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeTerritoryService etService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("~~ STARTED ~~");
        // Find employee-territories
        EmployeeTerritory et = etService.findByTerritoryID(19713);
        LOGGER.info("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        LOGGER.info("EmployeeID    : "+et.getEmployeeID());
        LOGGER.info("TerritoryID   : "+et.getTerritoryID());
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.common.repository")
@ComponentScan({"com.common.main", "com.common.service"})
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
# MONGODB Config
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/boot
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true

logging.level.com.altruista.guidingsigns=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
```

DB Collection:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried naming the field in the class "territoryId"? It's not a silly question.

Comment: use `territoryId` and add getter / setters (spring might use them)

Comment: Some debugging into spring might help figuring out

Comment: @RC. It's strange that finally our suggestions got accepted as the right answer, isn't it?

Comment: @RubioRic You should get used to it ;) (and if you really "disliked" that, you can downvote the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolved this errors. Please see my code snippet below. As per spring data mongo docs (Refer section 12.1.1): http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/

Your Mongo DB fields are using camel case letters and it's respective setters and getters, but as per doc "The default field name for identifiers is '_id' and can be customized via the `@Field` annotation."

```
For Ex: @Field('x') String id   


Resulting Id-Fieldname in MongoDB ==> x,
```

Similar logic you need to apply for all your field if you're willing to get data by any field(s).

Use below and will work.

```
@Document(collection="employee-territories")
public class EmployeeTerritory {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @Field("EmployeeID")
    private Integer employeeID;
    @Field("TerritoryID")
    private Integer territoryID;

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Integer getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }
    public void setEmployeeID(Integer employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }
    public Integer getTerritoryID() {
        return territoryID;
    }
    public void setTerritoryID(Integer territoryID) {
        this.territoryID = territoryID;
    }
}
```

Comment: What??? But that's the solution that I have suggested in the comments 45 minutes ago! And both javatechnology and javaHelper despised it. 00

Answer (score 2):

Only for clarifying purposes. I do not pretend this to be a definitive answer.

Maybe you have misunderstood me. You must respect java naming conventions for beans.

```
@Document(collection="employee-territories")
    public class EmployeeTerritory {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @Field
    private String EmployeeID;
    @Field(value="TerritoryID")
    private Integer TerritoryID;
    // setters and getters
 }
```

Should be

```
 @Document(collection="employee-territories")
 public class EmployeeTerritory {

     @Id
     private ObjectId id;
     @Field
     private String employeeID;
     @Field(value="TerritoryID")
     private Integer territoryID;
     // setters and getters
 }
```

It may, I repeat, it may be the reason of your exception.

Comment: @javaHelper It's weird. The exception seems to be referring to the model org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException . Model. Mapping. I don't undestand your comment. And someone has down voted my clarification. :-?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)